# Windows Vista home premium upgrade to Windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, license, upgrade

I have 2 laptops with Vista Home Premium editions. I bought the upgrade license from MS, to upgrade one of my laptops. I have upgraded one of the laptops fine. Now the question is, If I want to upgrade the second laptop but uninstall the windows 7 on the first one, would this be possible. I am only wanting to swap the OS onto the other laptop as the other one is faster. Is this possible? and if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technicaly, you will be able to install Windows 7 on both laptops. The issue will be when activating the second one. Unistall Windows 7 from the first computer first of all...

No worry, you will be prompt to call an automated line to check if you have it installed on several computers. Just say "no", only one, and you will be granted with a new activation code from Microsoft.

I had to deal with that a month ago and it worked fine for me. My license was genuine also.

Comment: Does that mean, the first laptop would be deactivated automatically?

Comment: No, you are expected to uninstall the copy from the 1st Laptop yourself. If you do not then you are breaking the terms of the license.

Comment: Can you then degrade to Vista Home premium automatically? is there such an option

Comment: No, you will have to reinstall from scratch